# Why making program listing with ACM style produces extra narrow caption?

Tags: listings, acm

I want to prepare a manuscipt for an ACM journal. The program listing appears with extra narrow caption, see at bottom. It is hard to believe, I found incompatility with package 'listings', in an ACM style file. But, the MWE works fine with styles  book, memoir, etc. Any better idea?

```
\documentclass {acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[caption ={Just to demonstrate an extra narrow listing caption}]{sample.asm}

\end{document}
```

[image: The extra narrow listing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acmsmall` class only knows `figure` and `table` so it assumes that, if a float is not `figure`, it is `table`.

You can reverse the logic whereby the `\@makecaption` selects the caption formatting styles, so it only applies “short” text width for tables.

```
\documentclass {acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\TabName{table}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\ifx\FigName}
  {\unless\ifx\TabName}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Just to demonstrate an extra narrow listing caption},float]
# some line
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={
    Just to demonstrate an extra narrow listing caption
    Just to demonstrate an extra narrow listing caption
    Just to demonstrate an extra narrow listing caption
    Just to demonstrate an extra narrow listing caption}]
# some line
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
\caption{some long caption to see what happens}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is perfect, until 'float' option is used in \lstlisting. :(

Comment: @katang I changed the patch; now *all* floats are treated like `figure` except `table`. In the example, one of the `lstlisting` is declared as a float in order to show the patch works.

Comment: Thank you, although I do not understand, why it is necessary to make exception with tables.

Comment: @katang The class wants to typeset table caption with the same width as the table